# How to show Product updated_at in Product viewing backend

Tags: magento2

How can i add this attribute to the product, so i can see when the product has been updated last time?

I know the data is in Catalog_product_entity -> updated_at. It just weird, it isnt in attribute set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking out loud on this one I have not tried it with this attribute but done it with others (in my case because data migration left attribute settings missing)

Some of the built in attributes are not shown in attribute sets, because deemed internal. You can modify them programatically or directly in the database - but there's a lot of things missing in these "internal only, backend only" items

First disclaimer is that **you have no control what changes this date**, depending on modules and synchronization it could change all the time and even when nothing really has changed. It might be better to create your own "updated" attribute and set it manually, or write a bit of code that updates it when what you consider a meaningful change has happened.

Export/backup both tables before you change them, just in case.

If you look at the attributes list table `eav_attributes`, there will be several updated_at (two in my case)

Find the one that is for products (note its ID you'll need it later)

At this stage this attribute does not have all the front end settings in the attributes table, if you want to display it you'll need to give it a frontend_label and you might want to set the frontend_model to match other date attributes (`Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\Datetime`). I also add a note in the note field when I mess with an attribute - so 2 years from now when hunting a mystery bug I can remember this is not as Magento set it up.

Next you need the catalog eav table `catalog_eav_attributes` and find the ID noted earlier.

the attributes you might want to set based on what you need are     `is_visible_on_front`   `is_html_allowed_on_front`      `used_in_product_listing`

(Note: I'm not sure if the admin side `is_visible` has to be set, for `is_visible_on_front` to work, it might have to be. If made visible I recommend hiding it in the attribute set - move it to a group that people know not to edit, just to be safe)

That should allow you to use this attribute in templates